# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, frameworks, entity

I got question on this error which I cannot solve. I am using Entity Framework database first. And before that I have deleted the entity model and create a new one. I am not sure it will affect or not.

This is my viewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MVCTutorial.Models
{
public class OtherIncViewModel
{
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }

    //User
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserFullName { get; set; }
    public string UserIC { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is requiered.")]
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserGroupId { get; set; }
    public string UserMMCRegistrationNo { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("UserName")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is requiered.")]
    public string UserLogin { get; set; }
    public string UserFaxNo { get; set; }
    public string UserDesignation { get; set; }
    public string UserStatus { get; set; }
    public string UserContact { get; set; }
    public virtual UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }
    public string LoginErrorMessage { get; set; }

    //Patient
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string PatientName { get; set; }
    public string PatientIC { get; set; }
    public int PatientAge { get; set; }
    public string PatientGender { get; set; }
    public string Hospital { get; set; }
    public string Ward { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string Race { get; set; }
    public string PatientErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CaseOtherInc> CaseOtherIncs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DraftCaseOtherInc> DraftCaseOtherIncs { get; set; }

}
}
```

This is my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVCTutorial.Models;


namespace MVCTutorial.Controllers
{
public class WardStaffController : Controller
{
    OtherIncContext db = new OtherIncContext();
    // GET: WardStaff
    public ActionResult Index() //Ward Staff Inbox
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult CreateTransfusion() //Ward Staff Create Transfusion
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult CreateIBCT() //Ward Staff Create IBCT
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult CreateNearMiss() //Ward Staff Create Near Miss
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost] 
    public ActionResult SearchPatient(MVCTutorial.Models.OtherIncViewModel patient)
    {

        using (OtherIncContext db = new OtherIncContext())
        { //I am wondering here why my local variable does not reference the namespace in this case is MVCTutorial. Is this why i get the null exception? I have check my database...i didn't have null record.
            var patientDetails = db.Patients.Where(x => x.PatientIC == patient.PatientIC).FirstOrDefault(); 

            if (patientDetails == null)
            {
                patient.PatientErrorMessage = "Please enter patient's IC number.";
                return View("CreateOtherIncident", patient);
            }
            else
            {

                Session["PatientName"] = patientDetails.PatientName;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("CreateOtherIncident", "WardStaff");
        }

    }
```

This is my view

```
@model MVCTutorial.Models.OtherIncViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "CreateOtherIncident";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutWardStaff.cshtml";
}

<h2>CreateOtherIncident</h2>

<h2>Reported By:</h2>

<p> Name: @Session["UserFullName"].ToString()</p>
<p>Email Address: @Session["UserEmail"].ToString()</p>
<p>Date:</p>
<p>Designation No.: @Session["UserDesignation"].ToString()</p>
<p>Tel.No: @Session["UserContact"].ToString()</p>
<p>Fax.No: @Session["UserFaxNo"].ToString()</p>

<h2>Patient Details:</h2>

@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.PatientIC)
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.PatientIC)

<p>Patient Name: @Session["PatientName"].ToString()</p> //I get the exception here.
```

I suspect it is because of the local variable, but I cannot find any further error or exception on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Before the exception, To check session should not be null.

**like:**

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.Session["PatientName"] != null)
            { //@Session["PatientName"].ToString()
}
```